# jQuery lazyload on mobile browsers when using back button

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazyload content on my webapp using the jquery lazyload plugin, and on first load of a page it works perfectly. This is the code i use:

```
    $(".lazy").lazyload({         
        effect : "fadeIn",
        container: $("#wrapper")
    });
```

The problem lies in the backwards navigation of the browser. When a user goes to a new page and then hits the back button to go back to the page using the lazyload function, any images that werent within the browser viewport will continue to lazyload fine, but any images that were last within the viewport that hadn't finished loading and displaying before the page changed will not load at it. So there are just empty space between previously loaded images and the next loaded images where the unfinished images are positioned.

Can anyone think of a way around this issue so that on navigation back the images that didnt finish loading either continue to load or load fresh?

Comment: still no luck with this. anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read some documentation, I was able to get it working in all browsers using the following:

```
function myLoadHandler(evt)
{
    if (evt.persisted) {

        $(".lazy").lazyload({         
            effect : "fadeIn",
            container: $("#wrapper")
        });

        return;
    }

        $(".lazy").lazyload({         
            effect : "fadeIn",
            container: $("#wrapper")
        });
}

function myUnloadHandler(evt)
{
    if (evt.persisted) {
        $.noop();

        return;
    }

    $.noop();
}

if ("onpagehide" in window) {
    window.addEventListener("pageshow", myLoadHandler, false);
    window.addEventListener("pagehide", myUnloadHandler, false);
} else {
    window.addEventListener("load", myLoadHandler, false);
    window.addEventListener("unload", myUnloadHandler, false);
}
```

Comment: Your "myLoadHandler" and "myUnloadHandler" methods do the exact same thing if the condition passes or fails. Cut out the useless code (for the children). ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by [back-forward cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching). Better explanation can be found in question
 [Mobile Safari back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979156/mobile-safari-back-button/12652160#12652160). Apparently problem affects only iOS5 Mobile Safari. This has was fixed in [1.8.2](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/commit/6ca5fafe22f6e991c4a8b0d59fe9328d74963d66).