# Back Button Does not execute any page script in Safari/FF/Android and IOS 5(Iphone/Ipod)?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, ios

I have a page which is dependent upon scripts on page load(script internal and external). When a page loads everything is fine. But when user click back button, no script execute in Safari, FF/IOS 5(Iphone/Ipad/Ipod) and Andriod? It is working fine in most modern browsers(Chrome/IE)

Addding this line will solve the issue in most browser except in Ipod/Iphone. How to solve this in Ipod/Iphone?

```
window.onunload = function () { };
```

I have found that I need to use,

```
    window.onpageshow = function (event) {
        if (event.persisted) {
            //Do my work which i need to do in initialization
        }
    };
```

Comment: back button in ios? you mean the back button given by navigationcontroller

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy, yes browser back button. IOS mean Ipod/Iphone

Comment: just try the SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979156/mobile-safari-back-button

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy, Thanks I believe this is the answer.