# Browser back button issue with Safari IPad

Tags: html, ipad, caching, safari

I am facing a issue with `safari` on *Ipad*. After logging out of the application, if user clicks on the back button then the application is loaded from the cache. I have used the following to fix this issue in *MacBook*:

```
<body onunload="">
</body>
```

But the above solution works for *Macbook* only and not for *iPad* or *iPhone*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Safari back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979156/mobile-safari-back-button)