# Codeigniter header not working in safari browser

Tags: php

```
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");     
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);   
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Not working in Safari browser. How to reload entire page if Safari browser back pressed?

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not related to the HTTP caching protocols.  Safari assumes a page that has already been loaded can simply be resumed.  The only workaround I am aware of is to implement a JavaScript event listener that will reload page.  [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979156/mobile-safari-back-button).